# What's valid as an event log data source?

Tags: c#, event-log, azure-diagnostics

I've been fiddling with Azure Diagnostics of late, and although the purpose of the following line of code is reasonably clear, the set of valid values that I can use in place of `Application!*` isn't (taken from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.diagnostics.diagnosticmonitorconfiguration.windowseventlog.aspx)).

```
diagnosticConfiguration.WindowsEventLog.DataSources.Add("Application!*");
```

What's the syntax for that string, and specifically... what does the exclamation mark mean?! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the standard Windows Event Log query. You can get more information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd996910%28VS.85%29.aspx). And some explanation about Azure diagnostics in particular [here](http://blog.smarx.com/posts/capturing-filtered-windows-events-with-windows-azure-diagnostics).

In summary - Application!* will get all entries in the Application event log. But you can limit this by being more specific - for example if you would like events from only particular source, or event event type.

Comment: what does the exclamation mark mean? I couldn't find it in the article

Comment: it is the delimiter between the target Event Log category and the actual query for that category. Your Windows Event Logs has a lot of categories, i.e. `Application`, `System`, `Security`, etc. Beside, you can create your own categories in Windows Event Log.